# Replacing text in AutocadMAP File using excel data

Tags: vba, excel, dwg, autocad-map

I have an autocad drawing with so many light fixtures with all different names.Now we have to change all those names, i already have an excel sheet containing two columns with first one containing "name in drawing" and second one containing respective "new name".
Is there any way to replace the names in cad file using that excel sheet?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the attribute and table editing capabilities of AutoCAD, but you may want to clarify. Are you replacing just an attribute value in a table, are do you need to replace a block in a drawing that has a particular name with another block?

Comment: No No i do not mean a attribute table , i have a text object in my drawing and i want to replace it.

Comment: If it's just a text block, then there isn't really a GIS component to the question and it would be considered off-topic here. You might have better luck on an AutoCAD forum. I'd imagine somewhere out there is a LISP routine that can check the contents of a text block when selected and replace it with another value from a dictionary/cross table such as your Excel document.

Comment: Off-topic!! The GIS component and CAD component are similar to some extent. Thanks for help!!!